# jQuery in windows 8 application (blend) doesn't work

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, jquery-mobile, windows-8, blend

So the problem we're having is the following.

We need to make the `<div id="navButtons">` disappear when we start scrolling the document.
The same div should become visible after we've stopped scrolling.

We have it working on this link: http://jsfiddle.net/zsnfb/9/, but when we try to apply it in Windows8 application (using MS Expression Blend), it just does not work - the app crashes on launch.

P.S we've included all the necessary .js and made references to them.

now following this instruction http://blog.adamroderick.com/2011/09/jquery-in-a-windows-8-application/ unfortunately it doesn't work

here is the code

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    // This function is called whenever a user navigates to this page. It
    // populates the page elements with the app's data.


    function ready(element, options) {
        // TODO: Initialize the fragment here.
        var b1 = element.querySelector("#ScrollableSection");
        b1.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
            var buttons = element.querySelector(".visible");
            buttons.className = "transparent";
        });
    }　

    function ready(element, options) {
        var b2 = element.querySelector("#button1");
        b2.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            var buttons2 = element.querySelector(".transparent");
            buttons2.className = "visible";
        });
    }　　　
    WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/html/homePage.html", {
        ready: ready
    });　
    WinJS.Application.start();
    $(document).ready(function) {
        var $menu = $("#navButtons");
        var opacity = $menu.css("opacity");
        var scrollStopped;
        var fadeInCallback = function() {
            if (typeof scrollStopped != 'undefined') {
                clearInterval(scrollStopped);
            }
            scrollStopped = setTimeout(function() {
                $menu.animate({
                    opacity: 1
                }, "fast");
            }, 300);
        }
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if (!$menu.is(":animated") && opacity == 1) {
                $menu.animate({
                    opacity: 0
                }, "fast", fadeInCallback);
            } else {
                fadeInCallback.call(this);
            }
        });
    });
})();​
```

Comment: Didn't you [just ask this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089943/how-to-use-jquery-in-windows-8-application)?

Comment: Please clearly define what "doesn't work".

Comment: Please use the edit function to update your previous question with your code rather than start a new question.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan some one totally edited previous posted question

Comment: @RobertLevy, that is NOT how this site is supposed to work. You don't alter the OP's question for your own answer's benefit.

Comment: Posting a screenshot of code doesn't really help.  If you're gonna post code, post text, not a picture.

Comment: @mblase75 I think that comment was meant for the other version of this question.

Comment: @Rocket sorry about that, take a look now :)

Comment: Why are there 2 `ready` methods? Is one meant to override this other one? Do you know which line it crashed?

Comment: @Louis_PIG unfortunately I couldn't able to catch crash line :(

Comment: @maanu Your code doesn't seem to be right for me, tho I don't have enough experience to say that. `$(document).ready(function) {` is this a typo?

Comment: @Louis_PIG: Good catch, that should be `$(document).ready(function() {`.